# SharePoint DSC - Build a complete farm with seperate machines?

Tags: sharepoint-server

I'm currently a novice to the Desired State Configuration thing and may not found the "right" source for this. I already created a configuration (ps1) and configuration data file (psd1) and even rolled it out to a SharePoint server.

But how to speak to other machines than the one I'm currently logged on? I was thinking about remote installation of SQL Server, about creating domain users on the domain controller, etc.

Maybe some of you have some sources or experience how to it right?!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use PowerShell remoting. Have a look at this: https://www.howtogeek.com/117192/how-to-run-powershell-commands-on-remote-computers/

But with the DSC you should thing about how to automate that process. PS itself has an option for the Pull/Push server which is bit limited. I am using Octopus Deploy (it is 3rd Party Product) to deliver my DSC package to the target servers.

Have a look at this blog there will be plenty of good info about SP DSC - https://nikcharlebois.com/

Comment: Thanks Marek! I'll take a look.